# Mistakes when connect to sandbox account Paypal

Tags: paypal, sdk, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am in the process of integrating paypal payment into my site.

but when I want to connect via the sandbox to a test account (personal or buisness),

I have this mistake :
"Something went wrong. Your sandbox account could not be linked to your developer account. Try again.

I did follow these instructions:
Visit developer.paypal.com
Login
create account test
Create application with buisness account linked.

I need help because I have been stuck for 1 week knowing that I asked for help on the paypal forum...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different web browser and a different live account to log into  [the developer portal](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts). Create one as needed.

Comment: I created another paypal account and tried again with the sandbox accounts, I still have nothing.

Comment: Use a different country. Also, there are default example accounts created for you.  Also you can link accounts manually created via www.sandbox.paypal.com, using the link above of `authenticate with the credentials of the test account you want to link`